# moderncv: Font selection and color customization

Tags: fonts, color, moderncv

For the following MWE,

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[12pt,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{Diaa}{}
\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \section{Education}
    \cvitem{Title}{Some Title}
    \subsection{Philosophy of Doctor}
    \cventry{year}{Ph.D.}{University}{City}{}{}
\end{document}
```

the output is

[image]

However, when changing the font to `roman` in the class options, the blue and black colors fade in addition to the loss of boldness of the headers and the output becomes

[image]

Therefore, my first question is how to change the font to Roman without losing the colors saturation and headers boldness?

Additionally, how to customize the color in `\moderncvcolor{blue}` to be, for example, `black!20!blue` without getting errors?

Comment: I measured the colors in the two cases and I get, in RGB, (56,115,178) in both cases: the problem is simply that the sans serif has thicker strokes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colors are actually the same, but in the sans example the strokes are thicker.

When `roman` is used, `moderncv` wants to use Pagella, leading to

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/qpl/b/it' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/qpl/b/n' instead on input line 19.
```

You need to countermand this by declaring your main font and also to remove the request for a (non existing) semibold font.

```
\documentclass[12pt,roman]{moderncv}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\bfseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\bfseries\itshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{\bfseries}

\name{Diaa}{}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \section{Education}
    \cvitem{Title}{Some Title}
    \subsection{Philosophy of Doctor}
    \cventry{year}{Ph.D.}{University}{City}{}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Declare a different main font, if you so wish.

In order to change the base color, use `\colorlet`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,roman]{moderncv}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

%\colorlet{color1}{black!20!blue}
\colorlet{color1}{red}

\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\bfseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\bfseries\itshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{\bfseries}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}


\name{Diaa}{}
\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \section{Education}
    \cvitem{Title}{Some Title}
    \subsection{Philosophy of Doctor}
    \cventry{year}{Ph.D.}{University}{City}{}{}
\end{document}
```

Here I have used red to give a very distinctive example.

[image]